# Windows 10 Linux Subsystem. initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I install MongoDB (in Linux Subsystem) with

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

and when I try to start it with `sudo service mongodb start` I have the following error

```
User@DESKTOP-TPQIRNP:/mnt/c/Users/User$ sudo service mongodb status
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
 * Checking status of database mongodb                                                                 [ OK ]
```

MongoDB really starts but what is this message/error `initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused` and how to fix it? Have a official solution to this problem?